# The text isn't showing up in rendering

Tags: rendering, text-object

when i render these 2 text objects in blender they wont show up in rendering, both objects are surface[image: 3d view]

[image: render]

Comment: read through the many possibilities of objects not showing in this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up

Comment: my project relies on blender render, not cycles

Comment: thanks i fixed it

Comment: i realized that "restrict rendering" was on for the text models

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up) #1 on the list.